# TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Having following code:

```
  it('componentDidUpdate should mount and change props', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = enzyme
      .mount(
          <JsonInput
            onChange={onChange}
            onValueChange={mockOnValueChange}
            value={exampleJsonStringValidated}
          />,
          { wrappingComponent: withTestThemeWrapper },
      );
    expect(wrapper.find(JsonInput).hasClass(':valid')).toEqual(false);
    wrapper.setProps({ value: exampleJsonStringNotValidated });
    expect(wrapper.find(JsonInput).hasClass(':invalid')).toBe(false);
  });
```

Gave me:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null

I was trying to pass `onChange` as `onChange` and  `onChange()` but does not work.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think `:valid` and `:invalid` [are valid class names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/12251171).

Comment: Thanks for comment! I was checking with: "expect(wrapper.find(JsonInput).hasClass('valid')).toEqual(false);" but still the same error.

Comment: Are you sure this is the part of code that throws this error?

Comment: This line throws the error: wrapper.setProps({ value: exampleJsonStringNotValidated });

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wrapper.props().value = exampleJsonStringNotValidated;
```

If not, I would appreciate it if you post your component code and the props.